# Unpredictable Pop up appears - How to handle this using Selenium (Java)?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-rc, selenium-webdriver

Here is the scenario.

I am using Page object design pattern(Web driver + TestNG). A pop up appears randomly on some of the pages during run time. Please note, they appear randomly on any page and I am not even sure about the trigger(Dev & QA team are geographically apart and there are several other complications to know about the trigger due to the Team size and time. ).

**Good thing is**: Though it is very difficult to reproduce the pop up manually, These pop ups are recognizable by web driver and they are html objects(not frames)

**The Problem is**: I have added check page event at every new page transition. And I am checking at every page load if this pop has appears. However, Web driver waits for the page default time out to check if pop up has appeared in every SINGLE page. This takes a LONG time during run time. Imagine if the Page time out is 120 seconds. Web driver waits 120 seconds to check if pop up appears or not in every single page.

Not sure how to handle this situation. I need to dismiss the pop up when it appears(randomly) and continue the execution on Page.

Please help. Kindly let me know if you need more details.

Thanks in advance,
Mike

Comment: Enable settings in your browser to block popup window.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can simply ignore the popups by using a handle to the main page and switching the focus to it after every page load?

This article on [how to handle popups in Selenium](http://www.thoughtworks-studios.com/twist/2.3/help/how_do_i_handle_popup_in_selenium2.html) might help you further.

Comment: The link isn't working anymore. It's the updated one: http://www.thoughtworks.com/products/docs/twist/current/help/how_do_i_handle_popup_in_selenium2.html and eventually i don't think it really helps with **automatic** alert handling.